# How to optimise React Native App Performance in terms of preventing component re-rendering again and again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rerender

I would like to improve component performance but after analysis of many components I got to know there is a very huge amount of re-rendering is going on with each component, is there any way to reduce the re-rendering of components in React?

Comment: Use `React.memo()` check out this article https://linguinecode.com/post/prevent-re-renders-react-functional-components-react-memo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re using a React class component you can use the `shouldComponentUpdate` method or a `React.PureComponent` class extension to prevent a component from re-rendering. In functional component, you can use `React.memo()`

**Memoization a React functional component with React.memo()**

Memoization is an optimisation technique. It’s primarily used to speed up computing by story the result of a function and returning the cached result, when the same inputs occur again. Following is an example of using `React.memo()`

```
const Greeting = React.memo(props => {
  console.log("Greeting Comp render");
  return <h1>Hi {props.name}!</h1>;
});

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  // Update state variable `counter`
  // every 2 seconds.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setCounter(counter + 1);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  console.log('App render')
  return <Greeting name="Ruben" />
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to try to avoid re rendering the component .

1. **React.memo or React.PureComponent**  ***(Best way)***
   find out more detail on https://dmitripavlutin.com/use-react-memo-wisely/
2. **Make sure property values don't change**
3. **Passing objects as props**
4. **Using keys to avoid re-renders**
5. **Avoid changes in the DOM tree structure**

you can find out more details on https://www.debugbear.com/blog/react-rerenders

Comment: Thank you , i knew the memo concept but it was a good recap !

Comment: thanks for the comments, I saw there are many other aspects as well to avoid Re-rendering for the react application e.g. inline styles are very much responsible for re-rendering, will share a not at the end of this discussion that every user can understand about my findings of the topic.

Comment: that would be awesome!
thanks @SurajSanwal